# Where can this story be found?

Tags: pali-canon, the-buddha, enlightenment, texts, monk

In the story the Buddha creates a golden lotus and gives it to a monk who soon after attains arahantship.

Story is in attached screenshot taken from the book *"Fundamentals of Insight Meditation"*, by Ven. Mahasi Sayadaw.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the commentary story of [Dhammapada Verse 285](https://sangham.net/en/tipitaka/sut/kn/dhp/dhp.20.bpit#s-dhp-285), good householder.

> Cut off your craving as one plucks an autumn lily with the hand. Nibbana has been expounded on by the Buddha; cultivate that Path which leads to it.

[Withering...](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JbeRRAvaEOw)... [old-age, sickness and decay](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=FDU0X9VVQn4)...

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchange, other world-binding trades, but for escape from the wheel]*

Comment: Thank you Bhante